# Laravel Static Optional Routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am looking for a "quick" and "clean" solution to the usual **http://project.name/products/total** where *total* is optional.

I've tried so far this:

```
Route::get('products/{total?}', 'ProductController@get', function ($total = null) {});
```

And then `$products = ($total == null) ? Product::all() : Product::count();`

But this not only works with **products/total** but **products/whatever**. 
I think adding `if($total = 'total')` is not a good practice.

I want the last parameter to be static, I am not thinking straight. I guess I have to avoid defining two Routes (`Route::get('products'...` and `Route::get('products/total'...`

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) is not helping either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To clarify, do you want `{total}` to be only a specific type, e.g. a number?

Comment: I want `{total}` to be the word "**total**". But optional

Comment: Can't you just tack on `->where(['total' => 'total'])`?

Comment: Yes, I can, but is it a good practice?

Comment: It's probably cleaner to add two routes since you have two different paths to do two similar but different things

Comment: Use a regex: `Route::get('products/{total?}', 'ProductController@get')->where('total', 'total')

Comment: @apokryfos, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your routes are in reality doing different things (even if they are quite similar) then you should probably add two different routes.

```
Route::get('products', function () {
      Product::all() 
});

Route::get('products/total', function () {
      Product::count() 
});
```

Of course this does imply that if there's code that's shared between the two routes you can move it to its own helper function/class.

Answer (score 2):

The *cleaner* way would probably be to have two separate routes. However, if you like you could add a constraint to your `total` parameter, to ensure it is exactly `total` if it is provided:

```
Route::get('products/{total?}', function ($total = null) {
    dd($total);
})->where(['total' => 'total']);
```

With this, you can hit `products` and `$total` will be `null`. You could hit `products/total` and `$total` will be `'total'`. Finally, if you hit `products/anythingelseatall` you will see a 404.